# Unable to get fileExtension and fileSize using Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

According to this document :
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource
I can get `fileExtension` and `fileSize` in files Resource.

I am using this line to get files metadata :

```
$files = $service->files->listFiles(array('q' => '\'USER_EMAIL\' in owners and \'PARENT_ID\' in parents'));
```

The query is successfull, I get the array `$files['items']`.

I can get the value of `"kind"`, `"id"`, `"title"`, `"mimeType"`, etc.
But I can't get the value of `"fileExtension"` and `"fileSize"` (not exist in array).

Is there any setting or query that I missed out?

Comment: mimeType can hint the extension

Comment: @DevZer0 yes I am thinking using mimeType to set extension.

Comment: oh, and the documents in my Google Drive are documents created in Google Docs, not files that i uploaded. Is that the reason i am not getting file extension and size?

Comment: OK,  
I found out that the reason I can't get the `fileExtension` and `fileSize` is because My Google Drive only contain documents created in Google Docs.  
I try to upload a file and I can get the `fileExtension` and `fileSize`.  
I feel so tired :(

Comment: Thanks for the clue on fileExtension'

Answer (score 1):

The content stored as one of the file types of the Google Docs doesn't include `fileExtension` and `fileSize`. `fileExtension` is not relevant in Google Docs context and Docs files don't consume any Drive quota therefore files have `fileSize` attribute is irrelevant for them too.

The `Files` resource docs include these details: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Comment: I was wondering the same thing regarding `fileSize`, thanks for making it clear!