# Getting file extension in google drive v3 and .net

Tags: google-drive-api

How to get file extensions in in Google Drive V3. I am using .net , here is the sample code to get the extension, but its not working! Any suggestions will help me a lot.

UserCredential credential;

```
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart");

            ClientSecrets sec = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                sec,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);

        }


        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;

        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file.FileExtension);
                Console.WriteLine(file.FullFileExtension);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your files created in the drive or are they uploaded in your drive? I successfully got file extension for the uploaded files in the drive. I used `fileExtension` in the files metadata. In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609274/unable-to-get-fileextension-and-filesize-using-google-drive-api), I got a hint of uploading my own files in the drive because I also can’t get the file extension of my files in the Drive (these files were created in drive not uploaded). It also explain that files created in the drive don’t consume any Drive quota so the `fileExtension` of the document is irrelevant for them.